# "exec failed: container_linux.go:345 starting exec failed scripts/script.sh no such file.directory found"

Tags: docker, hyperledger-fabric

I am able to generate the genesis block but when i try to start the peer to peer test network by using "UP" command it gives an error that execution failed as it cannot find the file scripts/script.sh.

I already added the path of my directory in the Virtual Machine of the docker toolbox.
note: I am using docker toolbox on windows 10: home and working with hyperledger fabric.

```
  OCI runtime exec failed: exec failed: container_linux.go:345: starting 
  container process caused "exec: \"scripts/script.sh\": stat 
  scripts/script.sh: no such file or directory": unknown
  ERROR !!!! Test failed
```

Comment: Docker Toolbox has very specific needs around sharing files and directories with the linux virtual machine required to run the containers. Because of this restriction it makes it awkward and perhaps not possible to use docker and docker compose to start up fabric. I would highly recommend not pursuing using docker toolbox and either upgrade to windows pro to use docker for windows or use a hypervisor such as virtualbox and run a linux VM instead for your environment.

Comment: Thank-you for the advice David. Actually i have already started pursuing this way but wanted to make it work in windows 10 home as it is helping me understand docker in-depth.

Comment: Personally I would say running docker on windows is not a good way to learn/understand docker in depth. In order to run linux containers (which will be the majority of container types) on windows (or Mac for that matter) it has to create a virtual machine running linux to host the containers. Far better to have a complete linux environment and use docker directly in linux.

Comment: Makes sense. Thanks a lot.